# Android AsyncTask results in freezing

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an API that delivers me the gas stations in Germany. I get the location and the name of the gas station using Asynctask.

I am putting these datas into a listView. For the listView I have implemented the `setOnItemClickListener` method, that is currently in `doInBackground`. If you click on a item, a new layout will be opened where all the fetched data are listed again, nothing special.

At the office I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 (Windows) at home I am using Android Studio 2.3.2 (Linux Ubuntu 64 bit).

At home I get the warning that the `setOnItemClickListener` should not be in `DoInBackground`. I know, that UI operations should be not there, yes.

But at office I don't get this warning. The syntax of the code is correct, when I start it from the office pc, everything works.

When I do the same at home, my whole phone (Samsung Galaxy S7) crashes (System.UI has stopped working) and even a hard reset did not work. For my home laptop Jack is enabled in order to work with Java 1.8 the API requires this.

The freezing appears when I scroll down the ListView and click on Items. Here is the code, I really do not know what kind of error this is:

```
public class ListOfGasStations extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
EditText editText;
ListView listView;
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
int size;
String[] locationArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_of_gas_stations);


    editText = findViewById(R.id.inputaddress);
    button = findViewById(R.id.buttonaddress);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listviewgas);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Test().execute();


        }
    });


}

class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        double addresslat = getLat(String.valueOf(editText.getText()));
        double addresslong = getLong(String.valueOf(editText.getText()));


        StationListResult result;
                Tankerkoenig.Api api = new Tankerkoenig.ApiBuilder()
                .withApiKey("MY_API_KEY")
                .build();

        try {
            result = api.list(addresslat, addresslong)
                    .setSorting(StationListRequest.SortingRequestType.DISTANCE)
                    .setGasRequestType(GasRequestType.DIESEL)
                    .setSearchRadius(5)
                    .execute();


            size = result.getStations().size();
            int sizeOfStations;


            System.out.println("Size" + size);
            locationArray = new String[size];


            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                //size of the station names
                sizeOfStations = String.valueOf(result.getStations().get(k).getBrand()).length();
                //get gas stations name
                String removeUmlaute = String.valueOf(result.getStations().get(k).getBrand()).substring(9, sizeOfStations - 1).toUpperCase();



                //get street names
                String location = String.valueOf(result.getStations().get(k).getLocation().getStreetName();

                locationArray[k] = location;



                names.add(removeUmlaute + "\n" + "\n" + location");

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            if (position == i) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ListOfGasStations.this, NavToLocation.class);
                                intent.putExtra("message", locationArray[i]);

                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }


        } catch (RequesterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void foo) {
        super.onPostExecute(foo);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListOfGasStations.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }


}


public double getLat(String address) {
    double p1 = 0;
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    try {
        ArrayList<Address> addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) coder.getFromLocationName(editText.getText().toString(), 1);
        for (Address add : addresses) {
            p1 = add.getLatitude();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p1;
}

public double getLong(String address) {
    double p2 = 0;
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    try {
        ArrayList<Address> addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) coder.getFromLocationName(editText.getText().toString(), 1);
        for (Address add : addresses) {
            p2 = add.getLongitude();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p2;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning may be different on different IDE version. There are some reason for freezing UI.

1. May be the listview item is so long. Cause listview load all items at a time. (**Solution**: Better is using `RecyclerView`)
2. It is true that you cannot touch UI element from async thread but you calling `onclick` in `doInBackground`. (**Solution:** use it in `uiThread` ).
3. You are calling onclick for every listViewItem that means you creating a memory inside doInBackground. May be it is the problem to reuse it. (So betting create `onclik` in `onPostExecute` or after finish `async`.)

Remember: onPostExecute call can destroy  async execution (Mean work in `donInBackground`). So i am afraid to using `onCLick` in `doInBackGround` may the main cause of app freeze..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But when I run the app from office (which is Android Studio 3.2.1) I don't have any freezes. So the freezings also depend on the used IDE?

Comment: Device is same? build.gradle (not app gradle) is same? I think your build.gradle is different from office

Comment: Device is same, but yes, the build.gradle file is different. At office the build gradle is 3.1.2, at home on my laptopt 2.x.x

Comment: So you think, moving the setOnItemClickListener outside from AsyncTask will solve the problem?

Comment: I think but not sure. But it is sure that if you use RecyclerView instead of ListView it will help to prevent ANR.

Comment: So using different build gradle will also result in different behaviours (at home it is freezing, at office not). is that right?

Comment: Different gradle version will beeffect on your app. I am telling you possible reason bro. That not means it is the only one reason for App freeze. ANR only occur when your app element running (So much work) on UI. I am just afraid on ListView. And i hope Listview is the main reason for this.

Comment: using RecyclerView instead of ListView is a lot of work. Not easy like Listview unfortunately

Comment: RecyclerView is also easy bro. You need just a adpater. And adapter. First time i was afraid on recyclrView but it is now easy. And it is best practice to avoid listView. ListView is deprecated too.

Comment: Well as you can see, I am using ArrayAdapter, so there is no extra class as an adapter. For RecyclerView I need to create an extra class for the Adapter.

Comment: Yes :) . And you can get ready made code in online. Put your item xml in adapter, set data in your view holder. thats it

Comment: Welcome :) And hope for best things